# Dynamically added function still running even after remove from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script has been added dynamically. It has a timeout function, means that it runs every 5 seconds.

**dynamicjs.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function( $ ){

$.fn.baslatmesajlari = function() {

setInterval(function(){ 

console.log("I am running");

}, 5000);

      return this;
   }; 
})( jQuery );

});

$("body").baslatmesajlari();
```

I load this function to a div using;

```
$("#temporarycontent").load("dynamicjs.php");
```

And when I do

```
$("#temporarycontent").empty();
```

The script is still running. How can I stop it run ?

Comment: You need to provide a way to clear the interval.

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to indent your code readably.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must have a reference to the interval id, then, when you want to stop it's execution, call `clearInterval(the_id)`

```
let interval = null //this is the variable which will hold the setInterval id
$(document).ready(function () {
  (function ($) {
    $.fn.baslatmesajlari = function() {
      interval = setInterval(function () { 
        console.log('I am running')
      }, 5000)
      return this
    }
  })(jQuery)
})
$("body").baslatmesajlari()
```

And then:

```
$("#temporarycontent").empty();
clearInterval(interval) // it should stop the function.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for making me laugh to the others who said "you can't".

Comment: They did not say you can't in the way "there is no way you can do that", Plalx said "you can't, you need a handle to the intervalId returned by the setInterval function", it means that you would not be able to do that withouth the interval id :)

Also, avoid globals, this is a nasty solution.

It's good to see it worked :) Abrazo che :)

Comment: @user3304007 We meant that you can't without modifying the plugin itself. By the way this solution is very bad as it's relying on globals. That means you couldn't have more than one instance of this plugin right now and the plugin is leaking it's internals so it's not encapsulated at all. Basically, this is not a plugin at all...

Comment: @plalx gotcha. Thanks.

Comment: @plalx already advised the user of the <nastyness> (i donno if this word exists in english) of using globals :), by the way, i vote your answer. Far more nice haha

Answer (score 5):

You can't, you need a handle to the `intervalId` returned by the `setInterval` function or provide an API on the plugin in order to destroy it and cleanup after itself. The easiest way would be to attach the state of the plugin to the DOM element on which it was applied.

```js
(function ($) {
  
    const PLUGIN_NAME = 'baslatmesajlari';
  
    function Plugin($el) {
      this.$el = $el;
      this._timerId = setInterval(function () {
        console.log('running');
      }, 2000);
    }
  
    Plugin.prototype.destroy = function () {
      this.$el.removeData(PLUGIN_NAME);
      clearInterval(this._timerId);
    };
  
    $.fn[PLUGIN_NAME] = function () {

      if (!this.data(PLUGIN_NAME)) this.data(PLUGIN_NAME, new Plugin(this));
      
      return this;
   };

})(jQuery);

$(function () {
  var plugin = $('#plugin').baslatmesajlari().data('baslatmesajlari');
  
  $('#destroy').click(function () {
    plugin.destroy();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="plugin"></div>

<button id="destroy">Destroy plugin</button>
```